# Linear regression across all the transcripts

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a dataframe named timecourse1 with colnames of time and rows of different transcripts as shown below. [timecourse1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkD8o.png) May I know how to do linear regression on each transcript at once? I have tried the codes below but it didn't work out. Really appreciate it!

````
  data = timecourse1,
  grouping.vars = c(transcript),           
  formula = expression_level ~ time
)```
````

Comment: fit<-groupedstats::grouped_lm(
  data = timecourse1,
  grouping.vars = c(transcript),           
  formula = expression_level ~ time
)

Comment: I also tried this fit<-lapply(timecourse1,function(x)(lm(expression_level~timecourse1$time,data=timecourse1)))

Answer (score 0):

```
unique_transcripts <- unique(timecourse1$transcript)

lm_list <- list()

for(u in unique_transcripts){
  
  lm_list[u] <- tryCatch({lm(expression_level~time,data=timecourse1[timecourse1$transcript == u,])},
                         error = function(e){NA})
  
}
```